# Convert Time to UTC Using GMT Offset

Tags: python, time, utc

I have a datetime and the UTC offset in the following format.

> 22-01-2012 22:01:30 +0530
>
> 12-02-2012 13:00:34 -0400

How can I convert this to a UTC using the pytz module in Python?

Answer (score 4):

I would use dateutil.parser from http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-2f49784d6b27bae60cde1cff6a535663cf87497b.  Make sure to use the correct version for your version of python.

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import pytz
loc_dt = dateutil.parser.parse('22-01-2012 22:01:30 +0530')
loc_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `python3`:

```
>>> import time
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> tm = '22-01-2012 22:01:30 +0530'
>>> fmt = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %z'
>>> time.asctime(datetime.strptime(tm, fmt).utctimetuple())
'Sun Jan 22 16:31:30 2012'
```

Comment: Hi Kev, thanks for the solution it work well in python 3 but don't seem to be working on python 2.x, is there an equivalent in python 2.x?